# How can I choose different device trees from inside u-boot for the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, u-boot, device-tree

I need to have different variants of a device tree passed to my linux kernel dependant on a board revision that can only be determined at run time.

What's the established way of setting up the boot of the kernel to deal with various hardware layouts that can only be determined at boot time from within u-boot?

Answer (score 3):

The `bootm` command is taking three parameters:

```
bootm ${kernel_addr} ${ramdisk_addr} ${fdt_addr}
```

While the third one is the address of the flattened device tree blob in the memory. So if you have different device trees, either load them into different memory addresses and pass them to `bootm`, or load that memory address with different blobs.

Comment: But how do I choose them? I had intended to have a new u-boot command that would output different names of the fdt dependant on board rev, but I believe it's not possible to take the output of a command and use it to fill an environment variable in u-boot.

Comment: Do you want to put, say, the same boot SD card to different boards and have them booted automatically? What are you using to determine the architecture?

Comment: Yep. I want one SD card that can cope with being booted on multiple different boards (well, the same board but different revisions causing h/w incompatibility). There's a set of resistors hooked off GPIOs that give me the board revision.

Comment: So how do you get the revision? You have a custom u-boot reading these GPIOs? Can it write the revision to an environment variable? If so, you can use the `if` with `test` commands which can be compiled with u-boot.

Comment: Look [here](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2011-March/089318.html). I think it is fully addressing you question.

Comment: Hmm, that's not entirely transparent, but it certainly seems the right idea. I guess I have an XY problem...

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but i recently add to deal with the same problem.

Using u-boot , you can actually write a macro for that.

The u-boot environment variable for the device tree file is "`fdtfile`".

From there, you can define a macro that set this variable according to your specific need for example :

```
setenv findfdt '
if test $mycondition = value1; then setenv fdtfile devicetree1.dtb; fi;
if test $mycondition = value2; then setenv fdtfile devicetree2.dtb; fi;
..'
```

Then you can just create a .txt file to register this macro and then use `mkimage` tool to create a binary image .img for u-boot to load :

```
mkimage -T script -d macros.txt macros.img
```

You can of course wrap this macro with a more sophisticated one that will be executed at each boot.